# BCC Tag not visible in email details using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

BCC tag is not visible in email details (even while checking original message) although the mail are being sent to bcc email addresses. CC tag is working fine

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: '123@jhb.hv',
  cc: 'test@test.com',
  bcc: 'test1@test.com, test2@test.com, test3@test.com',
  name : 'Test',
  subject: "New request",
  htmlBody: "<p>Test</p>"
```

this is the code being used.

Comment: It is the purpose of the `bcc`-field to be invisible to recipients, unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Not visible where?  To the recipient?  In the SENT folder of the sender?

Comment: Yes, it is not visible to the recipient...the BCC recipient is getting the email but the email details does not show BCC tag for that email.

Comment: BCC = BlindCarbonCopy. The recipient is made Blind.